# Prove that $\sin^2 \theta + \sin^2 \beta= \sin(\theta + \beta)$ when $\theta+\beta = 90^\circ$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

If $\theta, \beta$ are two acute angles prove that : $$\sin^2 \theta + \sin^2 \beta= \sin(\theta + \beta) $$

when $\theta, \beta$ are complementary angles, i.e. $\theta + \beta = 90°$.

My try... $$\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta= \sin(\theta+ \beta)$$
$$1=\sin(\theta+\beta)$$
$$\sin^{-1} (1)=90=(\theta+\beta$$

Comment: If you want to learn / improve your knowledge of mathematics then there are plenty of people here willing to use their time to help you with this, but pratically nobody wants to do your homework for you. Try to show some effort, try to be clear about what exactly are the things you don't understand and you will get help here. That being said; the hints below should be enough already.

Comment: Ok, see my try...

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** if $\theta + \beta = 90^\circ$, then what is $\sin (\theta + \beta)$? Also, notice that $\sin \beta = \cos \theta$. What can you do now?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly since $\theta+\beta = 90°$ we have $sin(\theta+\beta )=sin90°=1$.

On the other hand $cos\beta=sin\theta$ so $cos^2\beta=sin^2\theta$.

Notice that $sin^2\beta+cos^2\beta=1$, so $sin^2\beta+sin^2\theta=1.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the sum of angles formual for $\sin$: 
$$\sin(x+y)=\sin x\cos y +\cos x\sin y,$$
and the cofunction identities:

$$\cos(90^\circ-x)=\sin x,\quad\text{and}\\
\sin(90^\circ-x)=\cos x.$$